# Creating descriptor out of other Descriptors Using ArcGIS Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, fields-attributes

I created a Network Analyst route, and I just added a few descriptors in it.
I want to know if there is a way of create a descriptor based on other descriptor.

The equation is :

```
Descriptor 4 = Descriptor 1 / (Descriptor 2 + Descriptor 3)
```

Is that possible to do on ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use descriptors as an expression. You should use field evaluators in network analyst. Field evaluator assigns values to a network attribute from a field of a network source. In addition, ArcGIS offers other types of evaluators that can be used, for instance, constant, field **expression**, function, and script evaluators. See [this link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/types-of-evaluators-used-by-a-network.htm) .

with an expression you can create your own equation like this:

> Descriptor4 = Field1/ (Field2+Field3)